# Android Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper" Error

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application that contains google map. It works well when I update google play services and compileSdkVersion bigger than 25 but for some reasons I dont want to update it.

My app level gradle has implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0' and my project level gradle has classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'.

When I run the map I faced with this exception.

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/DeferredLifecycleHelper;
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:434)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3508)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
    at com.tsengvn.typekit.TypekitLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(TypekitLayoutInflater.java:223)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at com.tsengvn.typekit.TypekitLayoutInflater.inflate(TypekitLayoutInflater.java:75)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.tsengvn.typekit.TypekitLayoutInflater.inflate(TypekitLayoutInflater.java:69)
    at com.a1paradise.wifon.view.fragments.main.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:35)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2248)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2155)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2064)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:718)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.a1paradise.wifon-OQzxZ4QXyddZsMW-3OtizA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.a1paradise.wifon-OQzxZ4QXyddZsMW-3OtizA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.a1paradise.wifon-OQzxZ4QXyddZsMW-3OtizA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:434) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3508) 
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47) 
    at com.tsengvn.typekit.TypekitLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(TypekitLayoutInflater.java:223) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at com.tsengvn.typekit.TypekitLayoutInflater.inflate(TypekitLayoutInflater.java:75) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.tsengvn.typekit.TypekitLayoutInflater.inflate(TypekitLayoutInflater.java:69) 
    at com.a1paradise.wifon.view.fragments.main.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:35) 
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2248) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2201) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2155) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2064) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:718) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I also used useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' in project level gradle but it didn't work.

My compile and sdk version:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi include this dependency 
>   
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
>   
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
>   
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
>   
> implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
>   
> and add in main project gradle:
>   
> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'